# Installing Snappy core on alix 3d3

Tags: ati, 32-bit, ubuntu-core

So, i want to put my [Alix 3d3](http://pcengines.ch/alix3d3.htm) board to work and i wonder if i can install Snappy on it.

It's a Amd Geode based embedded board which is x86. The install info for snappy lists images that are only for x64 systems.

As it says in the "Notes" section: "We only generate and certify images which work on a 64 bit system. If you require 32 bit, You can generate the image using ubuntu-device-flash."

That kinda gives me hope, that this could work, but i have no idea on how to generate the image.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

We're working on making ubuntu-device-flash a little more accessible. Until then, my colleague has a [github repo](https://github.com/zyga/devtools) with a pretty handy shell script setup for image creation that supports creating i386 images. Simply run it-- it's an interactive script; it'll guide you through:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/zyga/devtools.git
$ cd devtools/
$ ./ubuntu-image
```

At the end of the process you'll have a .img file you can `dd` as in the documentation. Note that the `ubuntu-image` script will generate an 16.04 image though, not 15.04. By default it'll put you on the edge channel, too-- you might consider changing line 97 (`channel=edge`) to `channel=stable`.